# @Media Not Working in WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, media-queries

I'm trying to make a bootstrap-pseudo-table responsive, here's my code for my table: https://jsfiddle.net/mL3Lyuyx/2/ I can't seem to get Bootstrap to be included with the code when I link the fiddle, not sure why

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" name="viewport">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <style>
        div.services-table {border-collapse:collapse;overflow-x:scroll;} .services-firstrow {padding: 10px; font-size: 20px; border:none;} .services-table > .col-xs-3 {padding: 4px;margin: 3px;border: none;vertical-align:middle;}.services-firstrow {background-color: #65A6FF;color: #FFF;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;}.tooltip {position: relative;inline-block;}/* Tooltip text */.tooltip .tooltiptext {visibility: hidden;width: 280px;background-color: black;color: white;text-align: left;padding: 5px;border-radius: 2px;max-height: 300px;overflow-y: scroll;/* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */position: absolute;z-index: 1; border:1px solid black;}/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {visibility: visible;} .row:hover {background-color:#65A6FF;color: white;font-size:110%;}.centered{text-align: center; font-weight: bold;}.category {background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);}
        @media (max-width:700) {
        .row {font-size:80%;}
        }
        </style>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="services-table container">
            <div class="row services-firstrow centered">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>SERVICES</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>PROFESSIONAL</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>EXECUTIVE</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    <strong>AGENCY</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-4 category">
                    <strong>PRIVATE CLIENT SUPPORT</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-8 category">
                    "✔" Included • "O" Optional • "X" Not Included
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Crowne Dashboard Access <span class="tooltiptext">Online client support system for Communication &amp; support tracking and progress updates.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Dedicated Advisor <span class="tooltiptext">Words.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    Professional
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    Senior
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    CLO
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Administrative Support (Monthly)
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    10 hrs
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    20 hrs
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    40 hrs
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Junior Advisors (Monthly)
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip centered">
                        5 hrs <span class="tooltiptext centered">395$ Per Hour</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip centered">
                        10 hrs <span class="tooltiptext centered">395$ Per Hour</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip centered">
                        20 hrs <span class="tooltiptext centered">395$ Per Hour</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Senior Advisors (Monthly)
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    2 hrs
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    5 hrs
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    10 hrs
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Chief Legal Officer (Monthly) <span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip centered">
                        1 hr <span class="tooltiptext">Chief Legal Officer – $1,295 (hourly)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip centered">
                        2 hrs <span class="tooltiptext">Chief Legal Officer – $1,295 (hourly)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip centered">
                        3 hrs <span class="tooltiptext">Chief Legal Officer – $1,295 (hourly)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="category col-xs-12">
                    <strong>LEGAL</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;SWOT of Current Structure <span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Junior Advisor - Legal Strategy and Advice <span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip centered">
                        5 hrs <span class="tooltiptext centered">395$ Per Hour</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip centered">
                        10 hrs <span class="tooltiptext centered">395$ Per Hour</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip centered">
                        20 hrs <span class="tooltiptext centered">395$ Per Hour</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Strategic Corporate Management Meetings <span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    X
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Corporate Structuring
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    &nbsp;Annual Corporate Registry Fillings &amp; Fees
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        <span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Maintenance of Statutory Books and Records
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Professional Secretary of the Board <span class="tooltiptext">More Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Banking Implementation
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Company Incorporation
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Legal Department Management &amp; Oversight
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
                <div class="col-xs-3"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Quarterly Meetings of the Board <span class="tooltiptext">Quarterly management meetings of the board fulfill all legally required responsibilities of the professional board including reviews, new business agendas &amp; approving decisions regularly in compliance with domestic &amp; International laws.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="category col-xs-12">
                    <strong>BUSINESS DEVELOPMENT</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Crowne Round Table Wealth Mastermind <span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;ROI Annual Savings Analysis <span class="tooltiptext">Comparison of you current structure's effective tax rate vs. new structure's future projected effective tax rate accompanied by an annual savings analysis.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Private Placement Investment Opportunities <span class="tooltiptext">Gain access to private asset backed investment deals via our large global investment network and earn higher &amp; secured returns with little to no risk.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Annual Structure Expansion &amp; Growth Review <span class="tooltiptext">Crowne's legal team will perform a SWOT analysis of your structure taking into consideration current laws, both domestic and foreign ammendments to legislation, banking policies, and other global trends and changes which may put you at risk.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Corporate Management Advisory <span class="tooltiptext">Gain Access to the same strategic corporate governance, financial, &amp; business advisors used by Crowne™.<br>
                        Topics such as legal operation models, finance, tax, agreements, disputes and employee compensation structures &amp; models are regular topics covered by our experts</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Strategic Board Members <span class="tooltiptext">Professional board members are the secret sauce behind all the major "overnight" success stories.<br>
                        Leverage some of Crowne's top business minds and strategists to propel your business forward.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    X
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="category col-xs-12">
                    <strong>INTERNATIONAL OFFICE MANAGEMENT</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Corporate Receptionist <span class="tooltiptext">Your business receptionist answer and direct calls from your foreign office and direct calls on behalf of your domestic and international workforce.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    X
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Human Resources - Support &amp; Introductions
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    X
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Annual Filings and Company Renewals
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Mail Forwarding
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Office Set Up &amp; Management
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    X
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Foreign Sales Office Set up Assistance
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    X
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Hosted Visits to Costa Rican Office <span class="tooltiptext">Make your way to Costa Rica and our team will host you.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="category col-xs-12">
                    <strong>ADDITIONAL SERVICES (N/C)</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Discount on Additional Services
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    10%
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    20%
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    30%
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Tax Key™ Legal Analysis <span class="tooltiptext">Crowne’s proprietary legal analysis of the specific tax regime in your country of residence and our plain English breakdown and summary of the critical tax pillars which directly affect you at home.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Contract Review
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Concierge™ Priority Service <span class="tooltiptext">Crowne Concierge is simply the fastest access to solutions for your needs.<br>
                        Via a quick live chat we save you the hassles of picking up the phone or waiting for an email response.<br>
                        It is live instant message access from your pocket to ours desks from 8am to 8pm PST. We will follow up and log the conversation into the support tasks inside the Crowne Asana Portal to ensure all communication continue to be tracked and linked.<br>
                        Its simply about being at the front of the line.<br>
                        In addition to receiving front of the line support, Concierge members receive;</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Collaborate™ Joint Venture Structuring
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;Insync™ Partnership Structuring
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;American Express (Gold) <span class="tooltiptext">You are allotted one American Express Gold Payment Card.<br>
                        <br>
                        For more details please visit:<br>
                        https://www.americanexpress.com/us/credit-cards/gold</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;American Express (Platinum) <span class="tooltiptext">You are allotted one American Express Platinum Payment Card.<br>
                        <br>
                        For more details please visit:<br>
                        https://www.americanexpress.com/us/credit-cards/platinum</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Crowne Cards™ CyberSecure Payment Cards <span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    Bronze
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Crowne Accounts™ Checking Accounts <span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Insights™ Secure Offshore Accounting <span class="tooltiptext">See below</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Legacy™ Tax-Free Estate Planning <span class="tooltiptext">If you miss this boat, your estate may be taxed at over 50%.<br>
                        Properly plan the succession of your business and assets while you are happy wealthy and alive.<br>
                        Leave the legacy few only dream of and ensure your wealth transfers to whom you want and where you want it.<br>
                        Leave a legacy, not a bill.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Shield™ Bullet Proof Asset Protection <span class="tooltiptext">The golden rule of finance “Your money is safe where you are not” should never be forgotten.<br>
                        <br>
                        Via Corporate Cloud we can build you a series of asset protection vehicles which are impenetrable.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Perpetuate™ Secure High Yield Investments <span class="tooltiptext">Take advantage of opportunities in other secure regions of the world where central bank interest rates are 6% or more and thus creates large demand for private money at 12 – 20% secured rates.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Shift™ Expatriation - Change of Residency <span class="tooltiptext">Our team will work closely with you in choosing one of over 75 suitable countries in which you may legally take up residence and benefit from the low tax advantages and no foreign income reporting requirements.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Roam™ Second/Alternate Passports <span class="tooltiptext">Gain the ultimate in security, freedom and visa free travel by obtaining a second passport.<br>
                        <br>
                        We will introduce you to opportunities in all politically stable countries which have formalized legal procedures in which qualifying foreigners may obtain a second passport and then roam the globe freely.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;Acquire™ Offshore Payment Processing <span class="tooltiptext">Gain the unfair advantage over your competition by leveraging our unique international approach to payment processing.<br>
                        <br>
                        With opportunities and merchant accounts in more than 150 countries we guarantee you the lowest processing rates and rolling reserve requirements while legally mitigating your tax liability.</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    O
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="category col-xs-12">
                    <strong>IMPLEMENTATION (One Time)</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;1. Discovery <span class="tooltiptext">• Internal legal review, research &amp; analysis (3hrs.)<br>
                        • Discovery meeting with a Crowne executive who has specialized knowledge in your industry (1hr.)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $895
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $895
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $895
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;2. Strategize Plan™ <span class="tooltiptext">Words</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $12,850
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $12,850
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $12,850
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;3. Company Setup &amp; Registration (avg)
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $0
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $0
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $0
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;4. Bank Introduction &amp; Acct Opening (avg)
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $0
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $0
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $0
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;5. 30 Day Rushed Implementation
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    30%
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    ✔
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="category col-xs-12">
                    <strong>MEMBERSHIP (Monthly)</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3 hasText">
                    <div class="tooltip">
                        &nbsp;1. Corporate Cloud Membership <span class="tooltiptext">(1 HoldCo &amp; 1 OpCo)</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $6,150
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $6,950
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $8,450
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;2. Additional Partner
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $1,250
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $1,250
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $1,250
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;3. Fee on Incoming Funds
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    2%
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    2%
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    2%
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;4. Additional Company (avg)
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $1,250
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $1,250
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $1,250
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-3">
                    &nbsp;5. Additional Partners
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $1,250
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $1,250
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-3 centered">
                    $1,250
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Anyways, I used internal CSS with WordPress (so in between "style" tags) and it doesn't work at all, I just want the font to be 80% of what it was when it's full-screen and only for max-width 600px

I can't seem to recreate it not in my webpage, which is the biggest issue, but the page is here
https://crowne-law.com/testpage

Things I've Tried:

- Checking the Meta tag for viewport
- Adding the CSS to the customizer instead
- Anything else that's on Google so far.

If anyone has any insight it would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be

```
    @media screen and (max-width:700) {
.row {font-size:80%;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the pixel unit to your media query:

```
@media (max-width:700px)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
@media screen and (max-width:700px) {.row{font-size:80%;}}
```